# Column 'of realationship' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, group-by, max, having

I want to retrieve the row with the Maximum Value of 'PNRno' column, where PNRno is a Primary key of Tktrsrv and have realatioship with multiple tables. the code is written as:

```
 Select
 PNRcd,PNRno, Tktno, Tno, Tname, Doj, Class, brding, rsrvdupto
 from Tktrsrv 
 GROUP BY PNRno  
 Having PNRno= Max(PNRno);
```

Please help me.

Comment: You are not using GROUP BY appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

When using `GROUP BY`, you can't use any column in the column list which is not aggregated or mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause.

If you want to select just the one row with the maximum value of PNRno, you don't even need `GROUP BY`; use this query:

```
Select
    PNRcd,PNRno, Tktno, Tno, Tname, Doj, Class, brding, rsrvdupto
  from Tktrsrv 
  WHERE PNRno = (SELECT Max(PNRno) FROM Tktsrv)
```

Answer (score 0):

If Prdno is a primary key then you dont need to do a group by as each value can only exist once in the tktrsrv table.

Therefore you can select the max value with

```
select max(PNRno) from tktrsrv
```

and if you want to select from another table that has a foreign key to PNRno tktqueue is a tablename i made up)

```
select * from tktqueue
 where PNRno=(select max(PNRno) from tktrsvr);
```

Likewise if you want to select the data from tktrsrv that is the highest in another table

```
select * from tktrsvr 
  where PNRno=(select max(PNRno) from tktqueue);
```